# A function for spinning objects around a center point

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to code a game in C++ using SFML, in which several space ships attack a planet from different sides. I want the space ships that attack the planet to face the planet while they attack (obviously). The problem I am having is figuring out a formula that would work for every x and y position. If the sprite for the ship starts off by facing upwards, what would be the best way to approach this?

For example, if the ship spawns on the right side of the planet, the ship sprite should rotate to the left, towards the center of the planet.

Comment: _'The problem I am having is figuring out a formula that would work for every x and y position ...'_ What about the [circle function formula](https://www.google.de/webhp?source=search_app&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ofhfU82GJqqF8QfG74GwDQ#q=circle+function+formula)?? It can certainly easily be applied relative to any center x,y position.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I can see how the circle function formula would work to move the ships around the planet, so thanks for that. However, how would I know how much to rotate the actual ships sprites around themselves to make them face the planet>

Comment: _'However, how would I know how much to rotate the actual ships sprites around themselves ...'_ This problem seems to be more related to the [circle revolution function](https://www.google.de/webhp?source=search_app&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ofhfU82GJqqF8QfG74GwDQ#q=circle+revolution+equation) then.

Comment: You are going to want to multiple your point by a matrix. you may need one matrix for each axis, but I can't remember off the top of my head.   google "matrix rotation point"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well I read through some of the posts on that google search but failed to find anything that could help me. Do you mind elaborating on the equation and on how it could help me?

Comment: @user3586668 Sorry, I'm not that much in depth for that math/graphics field. I just wanted to point out, that it's a primarly math (geometrics) related question; not that I have a standard solution at hand.

Comment: The best way to approach these things is usually to draw a few different examples out. In this particular case, if a ship starts below the planet facing upwards, it should rotate around its center exactly as much as it's rotated around the planet.

Comment: I recommend you read about rotation matrices (https://www.google.com/search?q=rotation+matrix), quaternion based rotations (https://www.google.com/search?q=quaternion+rotation) and scene graphs (https://www.google.com/search?q=scene+graph).  Either of the rotation approaches should suffice.  Scene graphs make managing things a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the math for rotation, which is what you seem to be asking for, however you're probably better off simply using SFML's api for rotating entities: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-transform.php.

---

Rotating a point around the origin can be represented as a matrix multiplication with the following matrix:

```
[[ cos(a), sin(a), 0],
 [-sin(a), cos(a), 0],
 [      0,      0, 1]]
```

where `a` is the angle to rotate by.

(This can be derived from the trig identities cos(a)sin(b) + cos(b)sin(a) = sin(a + b) and cos(a)cos(b) - sin(a)sin(b) = cos(a + b))

Translating a point so that it is positioned where you want to rotate relative to the origin can also be represented as a matrix multiplication, and of course translating it back can be as well.

To translate a point by `a` in the horizontal direction and `b` in the vertical direction you multiply your point [x, y, 1] by the matrix

```
[[1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [a, b, 1]]
```

This produces the matrix [x+a, y+b, 1], which is the translated point (x+a, y+b).

To translate a point in preparation for rotation around a point (C<sub>x</sub>, C<sub>y</sub>), you first translate it by -C<sub>x</sub> in the horizontal direction and -C<sub>y</sub> in the vertical direction. The matrix for that is [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [-C<sub>x</sub>, -C<sub>y</sub>, 1]]. After the rotation you translate by the same amounts in the opposite directions, which is the same as multiplying by the inverse matrix: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [C<sub>x</sub>, C<sub>y</sub>, 1]].

Say your initial point is p, a matrix A translates it to be relative to the origin for rotation, a matrix R rotates about the origin. Then your rotated point is

((p × A) × R) × A<sup>-1</sup>

---

Since matrix multiplication is associative you can rearrange this to:

p × ((A × R) × A<sup>-1</sup>)

Which means you can compute the matrix ARA<sup>-1</sup> and then multiply any point by that matrix to rotate that point around a common center. So for each object you want to rotate, compute the matrix that rotates points around the object's center point, and then rotate every point of that object using the matrix.

When you combine the translation matrices with the rotation matrix you [get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1%2C+0%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+1%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B-A%2C+-B%2C+1%5D%5D+%2a+%5B%5Bcos%28a%29%2C+sin%28a%29%2C+0%5D%2C%5B-sin%28a%29%2C+cos%28a%29%2C+0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D+%2a+%5B%5B1%2C+0%2C+0%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+1%2C+0%5D%2C+%5BA%2C+B%2C+1%5D%5D) a single matrix:

```
[[                         cos(a),                          sin(a), 0],
 [                        -sin(a),                          cos(a), 0],
 [-cos(a) * Cx + Cx + Cy * sin(a), -cos(a) * Cy + Cy - Cx * sin(a), 1]]
```

Multiplying a point (x, y) by this matrix produces a point with the x coordinate:

x × cos(a) - y × sin(a) + (-cos(a) × C<sub>x</sub> + C<sub>x</sub> + C<sub>y</sub> × sin(a))

and the y coordinate:

x × sin(a) + y × cos(a) + (-cos(a) × C<sub>y</sub> + C<sub>y</sub> - C<sub>x</sub> × sin(a))

---

To try this out, say we want to rotate points around (1, 1). If we rotate the point (2, 1) by pi/2 (90° counter clockwise) we should get the point (1, 2), and rotating the point (2, 1) should give us (0, 1).

Plugging in the coordinates (2, 1) and the angle pi/2 into the equation for the rotated x coordinates produces:

2 * cos(pi/2) - 1 * sin(pi/2) + -cos(pi/2) * 1 + 1 + 1 * sin(pi/2) = 1

and plugging them into the equation for the y coordinate produces:

2 * sin(pi/2) + 1 * cos(pi/2) + (-cos(pi/2) * 1 + 1 - 1 * sin(pi/2)) = 2

Which means the point (2, 1) rotated 90° around (1, 1) is the point (1, 2), just as expected.

Then pluggin in the point (1, 2):

1 * cos(pi/2) - 2 * sin(pi/2) + -cos(pi/2) * 1 + 1 + 1 * sin(pi/2) = 0

2 * sin(pi/2) + 1 * cos(pi/2) + (-cos(pi/2) * 1 + 1 - 1 * sin(pi/2)) = 1

produces the point (0, 1) which is, again, just as expected.

Comment: wow thanks a lot! This is really helpful and answers my question perfectly. Could i just use the formulas for x and y instead of dealing with all the matrices? I think it would be more simple but I don't want to have to deal with problems stemming from that in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do i figure out the angle of rotation needed to make it face a certain point?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the derived formulae for the x and y coordinates. To figure out the angle to rotate by you can use the dot product equation `a·b = |a||b|cos(θ)`. a and b are vectors representing the direction the object is facing and the direction you want it to be facing.  The dot product of (x1, y2) and (x2, y2) is just x1*x2 + y1*y2. If the vectors are normalized then `a·b` gives you cos(θ), so you just use `arccos(a·b)` to figure out how much to rotate by. However this doesn't tell you if you want to rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Comment: To tell which way to rotate (whether to rotate by the above calculated θ or -θ) turn the vectors a and b into 3d vectors with the third component zero and then compute the cross product. Rotate by θ or -θ depending on whether the result vector points into or out of the screen. Cross product of (x1, y1, 0) and (x2, y2, 0) is (0, 0, x1*y2-y1*x2). So basically just compute that third component and if it's positive rotate one way, if it's negative rotate the other.

Comment: @Guri You should consider upvoting and accepting the answer (click the big checkmark left to ths post). It's always a bit frustrating if you put such efforts on a good answer, and newbies don't get how the site works.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried to but apparently I need 15 reputation before i can upvote a post.

Comment: @Guri Oh, sorry I forgot about these low rep restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the position of the planet as (xP,yP) and the position of the ship as (xS,yS) with its point facing upwards, direction (0,1)' (the prime denoting transposition to a column vector). To have the ship pointing at the planet, we need it pointing in the opposite direction of the difference vector

```
(x,y) = (xS-xP, yS-yP).
```

More precisely, the normalized direction of the point should be (-x/r,-y/r)', using r=sqrt(x^2+y^2). The rotation of the direction vector (0,1)' to (-x/r,-y/r)' is performed using the rotation matrix

```
( -y/r  -x/r )   ( 0 )    ( -x/r )
(  x/r  -y/r ) * ( 1 ) =  ( -y/r )
```

for the convention matrix-vector-product. If it is vector-matrix product, use the transpose of it.

Use that if specifying the matrix directly. When using rotation angles, the angle of that rotation is atan2(x,-y) in radians.